# why is this quotient module finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module

Let $\mathcal O$ be the ring of integers of  a number field $K$ and let $M$ be an invertible $\mathcal O$-module. It means that $M$ is a finitely generated and projective $\mathcal O$-module of rank $1$.

Now let $x\in M\setminus \{0\}$ and consider the submodule $x\mathcal O$.

> Why does the quotient module $M/x\mathcal O$ have finite cardinality?

I think one should use the fact that for any nonzero ideal $I\subset \mathcal O$ we have that $\mathcal O/I$ has finite cardinality. This is easy to show and you can assume it as true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a finitely generated torsion $\mathcal O$-module, so it is a finitely generated module over a quotient of $\mathcal O$, which is a finite ring.

Comment: What is a nonzero element in the annihilator $Ann_{\mathcal O}(M/x\mathcal O)$?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that $M/x\mathcal O$ is torsion.

Comment: $M\otimes_{\mathcal O}K\simeq K\simeq x\mathcal O\otimes_{\mathcal O}K$.